# network interface card has no ip

Tags: ubuntu, networking, networkmanager

After a distro upgrade to lucid lynx (v 10.4) I can't seem to connect to the internet (or rather any net) anymore. The 'nm-applet' does not appear anymore, even though the notification-area is in the panel. Force-starting the network-manager with

```
restart network-manager
```

the icon 'nm-applet' appears, but no NIC's are displayed.

'lspci' lists the network adapter I reckon should be eth0. 'ifconfig -a' shows no inet address. 'ethtool eth0' gives me:

```
Settings for eth0:
    Link detected: no
```

I need this NIC to be connected to a DSL modem (PPPOE), which used to work perfectly before the distro upgrade.

How do I fix this?

Comment: sounds like drivers, what network card do you have? is it on board? are the LEDs on?

Comment: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8036 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 10). It is in a laptop pc.

Comment: how about the LEDs? also have you tried ifup eth0?

Comment: LEDs stay off. ifup eth0 says: 'Ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0'

Comment: seems to be a driver issue, here is an old ubuntu thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=32676

Comment: I would check out the #ubuntu irc channel on irc.freenode.net those guys are usually quick to diagnose